# TensorFlow: Is there a metric to calculate and update top k accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, metrics

The current `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy` is only able to calculate the top 1 accuracy, and not the top k. As a workaround, this is what I've been using:

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions=predictions, targets=labels, k=5), tf.float32))
```

However, this does not give me a way to calculate the streaming accuracies averaged across each batch, which would be useful in getting a stable evaluation accuracy. I am currently manually calculating this streaming top 5 accuracy through using its numpy output, but this means I won't be able to visualize this metric on tensorboard.

Is there a way to have a simpler implementation by creating an accuracy_update function, or is there an existing function that already does this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could replace your use of `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy` by the lower-level [`tf.metrics.mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean), which is by the way ultimately used by `streaming_accuracy` -- you will find a similarity in their respective documentations.

E.g. (not tested)

```
tf.metrics.mean(tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions=predictions, targets=labels, k=5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The function works exactly as expected.

Comment: What datatypes and shapes are your predictions and labels?
I'm trying to use this function too but I get an InvalidArgumentError saying targets[0] is out of range..

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem (I was using the argmax(logits) as 'predictions' instead of the logits themselves)

Answer (score 1):

For top-k accuracy per batch, this also works.

```
k_val=3
accs = []
for each_bach in range(batch_size):
    acc = tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true=tf_class1[each_bach], y_pred=tf_class2[each_bach], k=k_val)
    accs.append(acc)

acc_data_per_batch = tf.reduce_mean(accs)
```

**tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy** returns **K.mean(
nn.in_top_k(y_pred, math_ops.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)** per batch