# How to calculate top-k in-class accuracies using TensorFlow Slim metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow-slim

I'd like to extend [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) such that it is able to evaluate the top-k accuracies per class. I hope it boils down to adding a metric to the following code snippet:

```
# Define the metrics:
names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
    'Accuracy': slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels),
    'Recall_5': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(
        logits, labels, 5), })
```

I already followed [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1286#issuecomment-317205632) to add the confusion matrix, which allows me to calculate the top1 in-class accuracies. However, I'm not sure how to get the top-k values as I can't find an appropriate slim metric.

To clarify:

- I'm not looking for the average top-k accuracy, but the per class values.
- I'm able to implement the required calculations using basic tensors, but I'm new to the slim interface and don't know how to do it using the above script.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate average top-k accuracy??

Comment: If you want to implement the average top-k accuracy in plain TensorFlow code, it should be straightforward to do so by using the [tf.nn.in_top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) method. If you want to use the TensorFlow Slim interface, I think you can actually use the code snippet from above: `'Recall_k': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(
        logits, labels, k)`. The name `recall` is pretty confusing in this scenario, but I guess the result is what you're actually looking for. See [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/recall_at_k).

Comment: If you want to use the top-k in-class(!) accuracies as well (see my answer below), you can of course just calculate the mean of those values. However, you should note, that the result will be the _normalized_ average top-k accuracy. So for unbalanced data, this isn't exactly the same as the mean of a per-sample evaluation.

Comment: You can also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799516/tensorflow-is-there-a-metric-to-calculate-and-update-top-k-accuracy?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, Actually I tried with following formula which gave me exact same result as Recall_k, 
slim.metrics.streaming_mean(tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions=logits, targets=labels, k))
I am guessing Recall_k will give me similar result as top-k accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution based on the linked [confusion matrix example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1286#issuecomment-317205632).

It's more a tweak than a beautiful solution, but it works: I'm reusing the confusion matrix along with the top_k predictions. The values are stored in the first two columns of the tweaked confusion matrix.

This is required to create the streaming metric:

```
def _get_top_k_per_class_correct_predictions_streaming_metrics(softmax_output, labels, num_classes, top_k):
"""Function to aggregate the correct predictions per class according to the in top_k criteria.

:param softmax_output: The per class probabilities as predicted by the net.
:param labels: The ground truth data. No(!) one-hot encoding here.
:param num_classes: Total number of available classes.
:param top_k:
:return:
"""
with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    # create a list with <batch_size> elements. each element is either 1 (prediction correct) or 0 (false)
    batch_correct_prediction_top_k = tf.nn.in_top_k(softmax_output, labels, top_k,
                                                    name="batch_correct_prediction_top_{}".format(top_k))

    # the above output is boolean, but we need integers to sum them up
    batch_correct_prediction_top_k = tf.cast(batch_correct_prediction_top_k, tf.int32)

    # use the confusion matrix implementation to get the desired results
    # we actually need only the first two columns of the returned matrix.
    batch_correct_prediction_top_k_matrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels, batch_correct_prediction_top_k,
                                                                num_classes=num_classes,
                                                                name='batch_correct_prediction_top{}_matrix'.format(
                                                                    top_k))

    correct_prediction_top_k_matrix = _create_local_var('correct_prediction_top{}_matrix'.format(top_k),
                                                        shape=[num_classes,
                                                               num_classes],
                                                        dtype=tf.int32)
    # Create the update op for doing a "+=" accumulation on the batch
    correct_prediction_top_k_matrix_update = correct_prediction_top_k_matrix.assign(
        correct_prediction_top_k_matrix + batch_correct_prediction_top_k_matrix)

return correct_prediction_top_k_matrix, correct_prediction_top_k_matrix_update
```

as well as:

```
def _create_local_var(name, shape, collections=None, validate_shape=True,
                  dtype=tf.float32):
"""Creates a new local variable.

This method is required to get the confusion matrix.
see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1286#issuecomment-317205632

Args:
  name: The name of the new or existing variable.
  shape: Shape of the new or existing variable.
  collections: A list of collection names to which the Variable will be added.
  validate_shape: Whether to validate the shape of the variable.
  dtype: Data type of the variables.
Returns:
  The created variable.
"""
# Make sure local variables are added to tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES
collections = list(collections or [])
collections += [tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]
return variables.Variable(
    initial_value=tf.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype),
    name=name,
    trainable=False,
    collections=collections,
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
```

Add the new metric to the slim config and evaluate:

```
# Define the metrics:
softmax_output = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_for_evaluation")
names_to_values, names_to_updates =    slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
            [..]
            KEY_ACCURACY5_PER_CLASS_KEY_MATRIX: _get_top_k_per_class_correct_predictions_streaming_metrics(
                softmax_output, labels, self._dataset.num_classes - labels_offset, 5),
            [..]
        })

# evaluate
results = slim.evaluation.evaluate_once([..])
```

Finally, you can use the additional matrix to calculate the top_k accuracies per class:

```
    def _calc_in_class_accuracy_top_k(self, results):
    """Calculate the top_k accuracies per class.

    :param results:
    :return:
    """

    # use a tweaked confusion matrix to calculate the in-class accuracy5
    # rows represent the real labels
    # the 1-th column contains the number of times that the associated class was correctly classified as one of the
    # top_k results. 0-th column contains the number of failed predictions. The sum is the total number of provided
    # samples per class.
    matrix_top_k = results[KEY_ACCURACY5_PER_CLASS_KEY_MATRIX]

    n_classes = matrix_top_k.shape[0]
    in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class = np.zeros(n_classes, np.float)
    for id in range(n_classes):
        correct_top_k = matrix_top_k[id][1]
        total_occurrences = np.sum(matrix_top_k[id])  # this many samples of the current class exist in total

        # top_k accuracy
        in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class[id] = correct_top_k
        if total_occurrences > 0:
            in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class[id] /= total_occurrences

        # convert to floats
        in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class[id] = float(in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class[id])

    return in_class_accuracy_top_k_per_class
```